# I am installing truffle by command, $ npm install -g truffle getting the error,

Tags: npm, truffle

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-wswUsmWo1aOK8rR7DIKiWSw9DbLWe6x98Jrn8wcTflTVvaXhAMaB5zGAXy0GYQEQp9iO1iSHWVyARQm11zUtyg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-wswUsmWo1aOK8rR7DIKiWSw9DbLWe6x98Jrn8wcTflTVvaXhAMaB5zGAXy0GYQEQp9iO1iSHWVyARQm11zUtyg== but got sha512-hGMnTmlfsH+gypVBDEb3jKJuG8wTqLt8h2RUmaQNXtatoZF/ZkQEjgnQtPUB5TapHuc3Cw4QIuGKw4y6ItYiMA==. (786432 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bilal/.npm/_logs/2023-07-29T03_27_41_124Z-debug.log`
```

I tried the following commands but didn't work,

1. rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
2. npm cache clean --force
   3)npm cache verify

Answer (score 0):

Try to update npm to latest version in CI before running.